# Definir correctamente una variable para ser leida en todas las partes del código

Tags: python, opencv, cv2

Buenas tengo este código y no tengo claro que parámetros le he de pasar a la función ni cuales retornar.

Me devuelve un error de que "grayFrame" no está definido. No entiendo si he declararlo de otra manera o en otro lugar.

> line 41, in buscar_circulos
>       circles = cv2.HoughCircles(grayFrame,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
>   **NameError: name 'grayFrame' is not defined**

**Mi código**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

# Función main
def main():

    cv2.namedWindow('ventana')
    cv2.setMouseCallback('ventana',buscar_circulos)

    while(True):

        ret, frame = cap.read()

        grayFrame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        grayFrame = cv2.medianBlur(grayFrame,5)

        cv2.imshow('ventana',grayFrame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


def buscar_circulos(event,x,y,flags,param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        circles = cv2.HoughCircles(grayFrame,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

        if circles is not None:
            circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype(int)
            for (x, y, r) in circles:
                cv2.circle(grayFrame, (x, y), r, (255, 0, 0), 1)
                print (x,y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ello, deberías utilizar variables globales, éstas van después de los import y se pueden llamar en el código como si de una variable más fuese, a diferencia de que para cambiarle el valor, hay que utilizar la palabra reservada `global`.

Tu código quedaría así:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
grayFrame = ""
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

def main():
    global grayFrame #Con esto ya puedes modificar su valor en este método
    cv2.namedWindow('ventana')
    cv2.setMouseCallback('ventana',buscar_circulos)

    while(True):

        ret, frame = cap.read()

        grayFrame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        grayFrame = cv2.medianBlur(grayFrame,5)

        cv2.imshow('ventana',grayFrame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


def buscar_circulos(event,x,y,flags,param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        circles = cv2.HoughCircles(grayFrame,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

    if circles is not None:
        circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype(int)
        for (x, y, r) in circles:
            cv2.circle(grayFrame, (x, y), r, (255, 0, 0), 1)
            print (x,y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Como bien indica el usuario @Saelyth en los comentarios de esta publicación, hay que tener mucho cuidado con las variables globales, aquí el motivo:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil

Comment: Cabe destacar que aunque tienen su utilidad, no se recomienda usar globals ya que muestra una programación pobre que puede dar errores bastantes problemáticos.

Comment: Eso no lo sabía, ¡Gracias! ¿Qué alternativas se pueden utilizar en su lugar que no implique la creación de una clase y el parámetro self?

Comment: Ojo, no es que esté mal usar Globals para scripts así pequeños y cosas controladas. Pero si el proyecto comienza a hacerse cada vez más grande, con diferentes archivos importados y varias personas trabajando en ello, usar globals acaba siendo una pesadilla. Es una mala practica que solo viene bien "a veces". Echale un vistazo a esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil Por eso, aunque no esté mal usarlas como solución para esto, siempre viene bien avisar xD.

Answer (score 3):

Otra alternativa a la sugerencia de @XBoss sería encapsular todo en una clase y definir un parametro en su inicializador, ese parametro puede ser usado por todas las funciones dentro de la clase.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

class MiProgramita(object):
"""Esta clase sirve para [inserta como funciona]"""

    def __init__(self):
        """Define variables que se inicializan a nivel de clase"""
        self.grayframe = ""

    def main(self):
        """Código principal"""
        cv2.namedWindow('ventana')
        cv2.setMouseCallback('ventana',buscar_circulos)

        while(True):

            ret, frame = cap.read()

            self.grayFrame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            self.grayFrame = cv2.medianBlur(self.grayFrame, 5)

            cv2.imshow('ventana', self.grayFrame)

            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()


    def buscar_circulos(self, event,x,y,flags,param):
        """Función que busca circulos"""
        if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            circles = cv2.HoughCircles(self.grayFrame,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

        if circles is not None:
            circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype(int)
            for (x, y, r) in circles:
                cv2.circle(self.grayFrame, (x, y), r, (255, 0, 0), 1)
                print (x,y)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    ClaseInstanciada = MiProgramita()  # Inicializa la clase
    ClaseInstanciada.main()  # Llama a la función main de la clase.
```

En caso de no entender como funciona esta solución, tendrías que leer sobre cómo funcionan las Class en Python (O en programación orientada a objetos, realmente).

Comment: Sí, esa es la otra solución. Yo es la que suelo utilizar por la versatilidad de las clases, permiten hacer mucho más y tener controladas las funciones dentro de las mismas.

Comment: Exacto. Es mejor practica a largo plazo. (A mi me costó mucho acostumbrarme a usar clases, pero mirando al pasado, fue una de las mejores cosas que pude hacer).

Comment: @Saelyth evitar las variables globales suele ser una tarea muy díficil si uno es principiante ya que por la facilidad de su uso se abusan de ellos(yo nunca lo recomendaria por eso +1), este tienen serios incovenientes a la hora de depurar, y muchas veces ocultan otros problemas, y al ser uno un principiante no entiende la razon, lo mejor es encapsular cada codigo y que sea indepediente de otro. :)

Answer (score 2):

Existe una tercera vía para hacer esto sin necesidad de usar variables globales ni englobarlo en una clase; pasar a la callback vía argumentos todo aquello que necesite. Podemos pasar un diccionario con la clave "grayFrame" y que tenga como valor el array (frame). Al ser un diccionario mutable, podemos modificarlo desde ambas funciones (en Python los argumentos se pasan por asignación). Se pueden pasar los argumentos que queramos usando el diccionario u otro objeto mutable como una lista, DataClass, etc. En C++ podríamos usar un struct, por ejemplo.

En este caso  [`setMouseCallback`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=setmousecallback#setmousecallbackhttps://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=setmousecallback#setmousecallback) pone a nuestra disposición el argumento `param` (`userdata` en C++) que existe para esto precisamente:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


# Función main
def main():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    params = {"grayFrame": None}
    cv2.namedWindow('ventana')
    cv2.setMouseCallback('ventana', buscar_circulos, param=params)

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        grayFrame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        grayFrame = cv2.medianBlur(grayFrame, 5)
        params["grayFrame"] = grayFrame

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

        cv2.imshow('ventana', params["grayFrame"])

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


def buscar_circulos(event, x, y, flags, param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        grayFrame = param["grayFrame"]
        circles = cv2.HoughCircles(grayFrame, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20,
                                   param1=50, param2=30, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0
                                   )

        if circles is not None:
            circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype(int)
            for x, y, r in circles:
                cv2.circle(grayframe, (x, y), r, (255, 0, 0), 1)
                print(x, y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Con `grayFrame = param["grayFrame"]` hacemos que la variable `grayFrame` apunte a la referencia del objeto al que apunta **en ese momento** la clave `"grayFrame"`. Esto aparte de permitir escribir menos código evita la búsqueda en el diccionario cada vez que necesitamos el valor, no obstante, si vamos a asignar un nuevo objeto se debe hacer mediante `param["grayFrame"] = obj`, si se asigna a `grayFrame` solo se modifica esta variable local, no `param["grayFrame"]` y por tanto no repercute en `main()`. Recordar siempre que las variables en Python solo son identificadores  referencia a un objeto en memoria.

No se si tu código va a funcionar como creo que esperas, la detección solo tendrá lugar en un frame (cuando se hace click) y solo se dibujarán los círculos en ese frame durante un instante.  Si lo que quieres es activar o desactivar la detección al hacer click izquierdo  puedes usar una bandera y realizar la detección el el mainloop:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2



def buscar_circulos(event, x, y, flags, param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        param["buscar"] = not(param["buscar"])


def main():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # Cambiar dispositivo si procede
    params = {"buscar": False}
    cv2.namedWindow('ventana')
    cv2.setMouseCallback('ventana', buscar_circulos, param=params)

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if params["buscar"]:
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(9, 9), 2, 2);
            circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 75,
                                       param1=100, param2=50,
                                       minRadius=0, maxRadius=0
                                       )
            if circles is not None:
                circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
                for (x, y, r) in circles:
                    cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)
                    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x - 5, y - 5), (x + 5, y + 5), (0, 128, 255), -1)

        cv2.imshow('ventana', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Al hacer click en la ventana se activa la detección, al volver a hacer click se desactiva y así sucesivamente. El filtro previo y los parámetros de `HoughCircles` deberán ser afinados para cada caso particular.